# Docker Blocker - Docker cannot find csv file in directory structure which is in project and in container

Tags: docker

Given this Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.8-slim-buster

EXPOSE 5000

ADD . /data/sample.csv

# Keeps Python from generating .pyc files in the container
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1

# Turns off buffering for easier container logging
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

# Install pip requirements
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN python -m pip install -r requirements.txt

WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
```

I can run this flask app on my local machine, no errors.  Pandas grabs the data from the csv and displays it in a return statement from the function (below):

```
from flask import Flask
import pandas as pd 
app = Flask(__name__)

df = pd.read_csv("data\sample.csv")
lst_one = df['col1'].to_list()
lst_two = df['col2'].to_list()
lst_three = df['col3'].to_list()

lang = "World!"

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return f'Hello, {lang} {lst_one}, {lst_three}'
```

However, after creating Dockerfile and requirements.txt and building image, when running the container, this error persists.  (Notice how the error message has the file path slashes going in the opposite direction from those in my code???)

```
[2021-04-30 01:34:04 +0000] [1] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.0.4
[2021-04-30 01:34:04 +0000] [1] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:5000 (1)
[2021-04-30 01:34:04 +0000] [1] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2021-04-30 01:34:04 +0000] [8] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 8
[2021-04-30 01:34:05 +0000] [8] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 119, in init_process
    self.load_wsgi()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 144, in load_wsgi
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 49, in load
    return self.load_wsgiapp()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 39, in load_wsgiapp
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 358, in import_app
    mod = importlib.import_module(module)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/app/app.py", line 5, in <module>
    df = pd.read_csv("data\sample.csv")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 610, in read_csv
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 462, in _read
    parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 819, in __init__
    self._engine = self._make_engine(self.engine)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 1050, in _make_engine
    return mapping[engine](self.f, **self.options)  # type: ignore[call-arg]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 1867, in __init__
    self._open_handles(src, kwds)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 1362, in _open_handles
    self.handles = get_handle(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/common.py", line 642, in get_handle
    handle = open(
***FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'data\\sample.csv'***
[2021-04-30 01:34:05 +0000] [8] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 8)
[2021-04-30 01:34:05 +0000] [1] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
[2021-04-30 01:34:05 +0000] [1] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot
```

Tried a different path, an absolute path, everything and Docker just cannot recognize that this directory/file exists.  The actual app I need to containerize has to be able to access data outside the container, eventually, but as a first step, I cannot even get Docker to recognize this data WITHIN the app.  So, all you Docker experts, please step up and let me know what presumably simple thing I am obviously missing here.  Thank you so much.

Comment: Remember that you're running in a Linux environment inside your Docker container, and `\ ` is not the Linux path separator. When you write `data\sample.csv`, that's not the same as `data/sample.csv`. I suspect if you fix your path things will work better.

Comment: Thank for checking this out. My current path making is a single slash. (“data\sample.csv”)   So, are you suggesting I write this line like this?  “data/sample.csv”?

Comment: That is what I was suggesting, yes.

Comment: Thanks. I’ll make that change and report back.

Comment: @JohnTaylor hey what was the answer here I have the same issue with it not able to find it... I even moved it inside the same folder as the csv reader. No dice.